# Help on System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Error

Tags: apex, failing-tests, custom-controller, vs-code

I'm trying to write test code for my custom controller and got a new error that I haven't gotten before. My research so far has told me that misallocated and/or coming up NULL.

Apex Class:

```
   public with sharing class AccountPricingRanges {

public List<CampaignMember> range {get;set;}

public AccountPricingRanges() {
    range = [Select 
             Id,
             Name, 
             Lead_Contact_Status__c , 
             Status_Update__c , 
             Status,
             HasOptedOutOfEmail,
             MQL_Date__c, 
             Campaign.Name, 
             Email, 
             CompanyOrAccount, 
             ContactID, 
             Shopping_Cart__c,
             LeadOrContactId,
             Alexa_Rank__c  from CampaignMember WHERE MQL_Date__c >= THIS_WEEK  LIMIT 100];
}

public pageReference save() {
    update range;
    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
}

public PageReference cancel() {
    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
}
}
```

TestClass:

```
@isTest
public class CMcontrollertest {
static testMethod void insertou() {

   CampaignMember testOu = new CampaignMember();

   testOu.MQL_Date__c= date.parse('03/25/2020');  //Date field
   testOu.CampaignID= '7011I000000WINeQAO'; //ID field
   testOu.LeadId= '00Q1I00000KVAhRUAX';

    //Create test records 
        PageReference pageRef = Page.MQLsThisWeek;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters(); 

   insert testOu;

   AccountPricingRanges controller = new AccountPricingRanges(); //call your code

   System.assertEquals(testOu.Id, controller.range[0].Id); // verify that controller variable is instantiated with the right value, ie previously inserted record


//Call pageRef mymethod
        PageReference objPageRef =  controller.save();
            PageReference objPageRefc =  controller.cancel();

//put system asserts
    System.assertEquals (objPageRef,pageRef);
        System.assertEquals (objPageRefc,pageRef);

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't returning any records. You should not use a hard-coded ID, but instead create new records in your unit test. In addition, the unit test is creating a record for (now) last week, but your query filters only on THIS_WEEK. You should make your date dynamic:

```
Lead leadRecord = new Lead(...);
insert leadRecord;
Campaign campaignRecord = new Campaign(...);
insert campaignRecord;
CampaignMember testOu = new CampaignMember();

testOu.MQL_Date__c= Date.today();
testOu.CampaignID= campaignRecord.Id;
testOu.LeadId= leadRecord.Id;
insert testOu;
...
```

You'll want to fill in the blanks (`...`) to suit your organization's data.

Comment: Ok - I see that now. Would I also have the test class create test campaigns and leads to add to those campaigns in order to avoid hard coding IDs?

Comment: @user3646059 Yes, that's exactly it. Always create the data you need for the test in the test. Salesforce will automatically roll back all records at the end of the test.

Comment: Thank you! I'll incorporate your suggestions.